# Retrieving data from moz_places in places.sqlite in a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, firefox, sqlite

I am using Ubuntu, my firefox version is 19.02.I am using sqlite3  version 3.7.9.I want to build a shell script that kind of involves retrieval of url from moz_places table in places.sqlite file

location of places.sqlite file-->/home/akshayaj/.mozilla/firefox/x3epy44.default/places.sqlite

location of my shell script--->/home/akshayaj/Shell Scripts/firefoxx.sh

My script so far:-

sqlite3 .mozilla/firefox/x3epy44.default/places.sqlite "SELECT url FROM moz_places"

It is giving an error:
Error:unable to open database file

Please tell me where I am wrong

Comment: when I write above code in a shell it runs perfectly, but it fails to run when I execute it as a script.

Comment: How do you execute the script?

Comment: first I went to the location of my script as mentioned,then I changed permissions chmod 755 firefoxx.sh,which was followed by bash firefoxx.sh

Comment: People with this problem may also be interested in my question and answer at [How can I see when I last visited a web site accurate to better than one minute?](https://superuser.com/questions/1568047/how-can-i-see-when-i-last-visited-a-web-site-accurate-to-better-than-one-minute/1568055#1568055), which also touches on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox locks the *places.sqlite* database while it's running.
[Read this](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_locking_mode) to know this feature.

Either close the firefox or copy the places.sqlite file to another location and then try to create a connection.

Comment: It worked!!!cant express in words man,how happy I am,I was stumbled upon this problem from a week,thanx a ton :)

Comment: by the way I copied it to another location

Answer (score 0):

When you want to access the file `/home/akshayaj/.mozilla/firefox/x3epy44.default/places.sqlite`, you should actually use that path, and not omit the first two directories.

You could also use `~` as a shortcut for you home directory: `~/.mozilla/firefox/x3epy44.default/places.sqlite`.

Comment: Before asking here I tried including the first two directories which gave the same error..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
wget -cq https://raw2.github.com/websafe/ffbx/master/ffbx.sh \
    && sh ffbx.sh
```

Or just download [ffbx.sh](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/websafe/ffbx/master/ffbx.sh) and use it as described in the [README](https://github.com/websafe/ffbx/blob/master/README.md).

Without any params `ffbx` will search all `places.sqlite` files found in ~/.mozilla/firefox subdirectories.

```
ffbx.sh
```

an example result:

```
1391725993809844        ffbx-example    Bookmarks Toolbar       https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/central/  Getting Started
1391725993811277        ffbx-example    Mozilla Firefox https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/help/     Help and Tutorials
1391725993812029        ffbx-example    Mozilla Firefox https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/customize/        Customize Firefox
1391725993812829        ffbx-example    Mozilla Firefox https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/contribute/       Get Involved
1391725993813492        ffbx-example    Mozilla Firefox https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/    About Us
1391725993870487        ffbx-example    Bookmarks Toolbar       place:sort=8&maxResults=10      Most Visited
1391725993870988        ffbx-example    Bookmarks Menu  place:folder=BOOKMARKS_MENU&folder=UNFILED_BOOKMARKS&folder=TOOLBAR&queryType=1&sort=12&maxResults=10&excludeQueries=1  Recently Bookmarked
1391725993871436        ffbx-example    Bookmarks Menu  place:type=6&sort=14&maxResults=10      Recent Tags
1391726063106065        ffbx-example    Unsorted Bookmarks      https://github.com/websafe/ffbx websafe/ffbx · GitHub   Firefox,bookmarks,extract,Bash,script,SQLite
```

The output contains TAB separated columns for each bookmark:

- modification timestamp,
- profile name,
- bookmark folder,
- url,
- title,
- tags.

When used with a parameter:

```
ffbx.sh /home/akshayaj/.mozilla/firefox/x3epy44.default/places.sqlite
```

the output will contain only entries for the specified `places.sqlite` file and the `profile name` column will be missing:

```
1391725993809844        Bookmarks Toolbar       https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/central/  Getting Started
1391725993811277        Mozilla Firefox https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/help/     Help and Tutorials
1391725993812029        Mozilla Firefox https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/customize/        Customize Firefox
1391725993812829        Mozilla Firefox https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/contribute/       Get Involved
1391725993813492        Mozilla Firefox https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/    About Us
1391725993870487        Bookmarks Toolbar       place:sort=8&maxResults=10      Most Visited
1391725993870988        Bookmarks Menu  place:folder=BOOKMARKS_MENU&folder=UNFILED_BOOKMARKS&folder=TOOLBAR&queryType=1&sort=12&maxResults=10&excludeQueries=1  Recently Bookmarked
1391725993871436        Bookmarks Menu  place:type=6&sort=14&maxResults=10      Recent Tags
1391726063106065        Unsorted Bookmarks      https://github.com/websafe/ffbx websafe/ffbx · GitHub   Firefox,bookmarks,extract,Bash,script,SQLite,
```

[Check the README for more examples.](https://github.com/websafe/ffbx/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: This script works for me, but it is very slow (due to issuing separate SQL queries for each entry found), outputting no more than 2 URLs per second on my machine. I have 47K unique URLs in my history.

Comment: @reinierpost I'm aware of this, I'll try to fix this problem ~next week.
https://github.com/websafe/ffbx/issues/3