# How to obtain the MIME type of URLs in the Firefox history?

Tags: sqlite, firefox, browser-history

[Firefox keeps its list of visited URLs on disk in a SQLite database](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Places/Database), so it is easy to write [a script to output that list in CSV format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744990/retrieving-data-from-moz-places-in-places-sqlite-in-a-shell-script#21617284).

However, I need to select among URLs based on MIME type (I want to recover my list of RSS/Atom feeds).

Does Firefox maintain that information anywhere?

(I can write a script to issue a HEAD request on each URL in the list and record the MIME type returned.  With 47K URLs, that isn't the politest thing to do, so I'm looking for a way to avoid it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**
Sadly it looks like impoliteness may be the only way... Firefox doesn't seem to store this information in its history.

**Workings:**
I dumped my own `places.sqlite` database to a text file using the following commands:

```
.open places.sqlite
.mode csv
.headers on
.out places.dmp
.dump
```

Searching through this file in a text editor reveals there are no references to `text/` in the data and the only usage of `mime_type` in the schema is in unrelated tables (`moz_favicons`, `moz_annos` and `moz_items_annos`, each of which serves a different purpose).

Comment: I did the same (`.schema` is helpful, too).  I also generated an approximate database diagram to see the relationships between the tables. Meanwhile I've written [a script that issues a HEAD request on all of my URLs](https://www.win.tue.nl/~rp/bin/urlheadinfo).  It does hundreds of URLs per second, so I'm going for that solution.